# Erro no build do Vue.js no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.5

### Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao salvar o arquivo app.js:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R27w.jpg

*Os arquvios são esses:*

**app.js:**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('topo',require('./components/Topo.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**Topo.vue:**

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" v-bind:href="url">
                {{ titulo }}
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['titulo','url']
}
</script>
```

***O erro só acontece quando coloco a linha*** `"Vue.component('topo',require('./components/Topo.vue'));"` ***no app.js***

Alguém sabe qual é o problema?

Answer (score 1):

O erro estava no `<button>` em

```
aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}"
```

o correto seria :

```
aria-label="('Toggle navigation')"
```